# How to open a pdf in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

> for web api I am returing the pdf as :-

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
[HttpGet]
public byte[] GetReportData()
{
 string filePath = "D:\\Decoding.pdf";
 byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
 return bytes;
}
```

I am calling the method in my action and reducer as:-

Action:-

```
export  function LoadReportData () {
    return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: REQUEST_REPORT,//defining the name of the action to identify in the reducer
    });

    fetch(APIPATH+'Requisition/GetReportData')//calling the service
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((report) => dispatch(receiveReport(report)));//passing the data to other actions
  }
}


//this method use to pass the data coming for the lab test result to the component
export  function receiveReport(report) {

  return {
    type:RECEIVE_REPORT,//defining the name of the action to identify in the reducer
    report:report//passing the data to reducer
  };
}
```

Reducers:-

```
case  'RECEIVE_REPORT':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          report: action.report,
          loadingReport: false,
        });
    case 'REQUEST_REPORT':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          loadingReport: true
        });
```

Now the report is coming as byte as I passed from the web api. Now my requirement is how can I display this pdf file that is coming as byte array from the web api in my component or next tab of browser?.
**Note: report contains the array of bytes**

Answer (score 0):

you have to use pdfbox which is available as jar to open pdf files

Answer (score 0):

You should install [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf)

```
Install with npm install react-pdf
```

Use in your app:

```
var PDF = require('react-pdf');

var MyApp = React.createClass({
  render() {

    return '<PDF content="YSBzaW1wbGUgcGRm..." page="1" scale="1.0" onDocumentComplete={this._onDocumentComplete} onPageComplete={this._onPageComplete} loading={(<span>Your own loading message ...</span>)} />';
  },
  _onDocumentCompleted(pages){
    this.setState({pages});
  },
  _onPageCompleted(page){
    this.setState({currentPage: page});
  }
});
```

Comment: @Vadim I tried it but  "Uncaught ReferenceError: PDFJS is not defined" is coming as error

Answer (score 0):

> I am posting my code which is working fine for me:-

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import PDF from "react-pdfjs";
class PreviewComponent extends Component{
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      reportData:this.props.reportData,
      page:1,
      scale:1.0
    }
   this.onDocumentCompleted=this._onDocumentCompleted.bind(this);
     this.onPageCompleted=this._onPageCompleted.bind(this);
  }

 render() {
        return <PDF content={this.state.reportData} page={this.state.page} scale={this.state.scale} onDocumentComplete={this._onDocumentComplete} onPageComplete={this._onPageComplete} loading={(<span>Your own loading message ...</span>)} />
  }
  _onDocumentCompleted(pages){
    this.setState({pages: pages});
  }
  _onPageCompleted(page){
    this.setState({currentPage: page});
  }
}
export default PreviewComponent;
```