# How to open a pdf in new tab in reactjs?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, react-redux

> We have the pdf document save in data base , from webapi I am
>   returning as byte array,Now from UI I have to open the pdf in new tab
>   of browser, and user should able to download the pdf. How can I
>   achieve this requirement of **opening and downloading the pdf document**?

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504668/how-to-open-a-pdf-in-reactjs has some answers, seems answer may lie in the React module react-pdf or react-pdfjs

Comment: @Jayce444 I did the same but, problem is that we can't download opened pdf. If you will right click then it will save as the image.But my requirement is to download the opened pdf.

Comment: @Jayce444 do you have any better solution for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<a href='/api/v1/print/example.pdf' target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
```

Comment: I tried window.open(this.state.path, "_blank"); but its not identifying the path while the path is correct : Cannot GET /Decoding.pdf and in browser Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) error is coming

Comment: @jack Can you write what does the path contain?

Answer (score 22):

The following code work for me

```
try {
    await axios
      .get(uri.ApiBaseUrl + "AccountReport/GetTrialBalancePdfReport", {
        responseType: "blob",
        params: {
          ...searchObject,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        //Create a Blob from the PDF Stream
        const file = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
        //Build a URL from the file
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        //Open the URL on new Window
         const pdfWindow = window.open();
         pdfWindow.location.href = fileURL;            
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    return { error };
  }
```

Comment: THX for that. But keep in mind, that it doesnt work for Safari.

Answer (score 13):

> ## Solution from 2020

```
   import Pdf from '../Documents/Document.pdf';

   <a href={Pdf} without rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
      <button trailingIcon="picture_as_pdf" label="Resume">
        PDF
      </button>
   </a>
```

Comment: Thanks. The only solution that worked for me. The only solution that actually uses PDF from local files

Comment: Great, I glad it helps you @Alexander

Comment: it works, but adding random number at the end of file, for example file name is "abc.pdf" but showing "abc.3987n34.pdf", Any reason?

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking off of **Qui-Gon Jinn**'s answer, I also had the same issue mentioned by **Pardeep Jain**.

I managed to avoid the random name generation at the end of the file name by placing my PDF inside my public/assets folder (shown below).

[image: pdf placement in file structure]

Then, to actually display the PDF, I slightly altered the code.

```
<a href={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/abc.pdf`} rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
   PDF 
</a>
```

The use of an .env file is necessary as React does not allow the import of anything outside of the src folder.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, React doesn't allow you to directly reference the path in the href tag, so you need to import it at the top of your file.

```
import PDF from "file.pdf"
```

Then use it in your href ->

```
<a href={PDF} without rel='noreferrer' target='_blank'>
    PDF here
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is for downloading any type of file like PDF having a condition if fileType is PDF then it will open in new tab on clicking on it. This is because it depends on user either view the image or download it.

**FRONTEND (ReactJs)**

```js
const downloadFile = (fileID, fileName) => {
    axios.get(`${URL}/download/${fileID}`, {
      responseType: 'blob'
    }).then((res) => {
      const fileType = res.headers['content-type']
      const blob = new Blob([res.data], {
        type: fileType
      });
      console.log('fileType = ',fileType);
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      if (fileType.includes('pdf')) {
        window.open(url)
        a.href = null;
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      }
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = url;
      a.download = fileName;
      a.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.message)
    });
```

**BACKEND (ExpressJs)**

```js
app.get('/download/:id',(req,res)=>{ 
    const id = req.params.id;

    connection.query('SELECT path FROM file_table WHERE file_id=?', [id], (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(404).json({
                message: err.message
            })
        }
        const filePath = data[0].path;
        res.download(filePath, (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            else console.log('file is downloaded');
        });
    })
})
```